# Extended Reports Extension - reports do not appear

Tags: extension, reports

I have installed the Extended Reports Extension, but cannot see any reports, or any configuration options related to them.  Where should I be looking?

I have tried on two installations with the same result:

Extended Reports 3.5;  CiviCRM 5.5.1; Drupal 7.60-dev; PHP 7.2.11-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

Extended Reports 3.5;  CiviCRM 5.3.0; Drupal 7.59; PHP 7.1.16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extended report lists the newly added report as a template, so you need to look at `civicrm/admin/report/template/list?reset=1`, i.e, `Administer -> CiviReport -> Create New Report from Template` menu path.

Click on any template to create your required report.